# cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport with search doesn't display the value

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular15, mat-select, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

It has been days that I am trying to fix some angular 15 code but I can't find the solution.
I am using a mat-select(Legacy) with ngx-mat-select-search and virtual scroll cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport.
When I select a value, it is displayed, but when I search for some value, it's not displayed but it's read, I can display it in my console but not in my mat-select.

I am facing the same problem in [this stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-9fxc91?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexamples%2F01-single-selection-example%2Fsingle-selection-example.component.html), you can search for "Bank C" and select it, it's displayed, but when you search for "Bank Q" and select it, the value is not displayed.

Here's my html code :

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select [formControl]="formControl"
            [placeholder]="placeholder"
            [(ngModel)]="values"
            [matTooltip]="getTooltip(values)"
            [multiple]="multiple"
            [required]="required"
            (openedChange)="openChange($event)">

    <mat-option *ngIf="!hideSearch">
        <ngx-mat-select-search
            [placeholderLabel]="filterItem"
            [noEntriesFoundLabel]="noItemMatch"
            [formControl]="filterItemCtrl"
            [showToggleAllCheckbox]="showAllCheckbox"
            [toggleAllCheckboxChecked]="showAllCheckbox && multiple && items.length && values.length === items.length"
            (toggleAll)="checkAllItems($event)">
        </ngx-mat-select-search>
    </mat-option>

    <mat-option *ngIf="emptyItem">{{ emptyItem }}</mat-option>

    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize]="5" [style.height.px]=viewPortHeightPx class="custom-viewport">
        <mat-option *cdkVirtualFor="let item of filteredItems | async;" 
                    [value]="item"
                    (onSelectionChange)="clickOption($event)">
            <div >
                {{ item }}
            </div>
         </mat-option>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</mat-select>
```

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one was really tough to debug, but basically the problem was that when an `mat-option` is outside the rendering window of the virtual scroll the option will not get selected, so I wrote a special slice method, that will always place the selected bank on the top of the array, so that will get surely selected and that fixed your issue.

```
  getCorrectSlice(): Bank[] {
    const output = this.banks.slice();
    const bank: Bank = this.bankCtrl.value;
    if (bank) {
      return [bank, ...this.banks];
    }
    return this.banks.slice();
  }
```

Above code creates the slice with the selected value in the beginning!

html

```
<h3>Single selection</h3>
<p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select
      id="bank"
      id="bank"
      [formControl]="bankCtrl"
      placeholder="Bank"
      #singleSelect
      [compareWith]="compareWith"
      (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)"
    >
      <mat-option>
        <ngx-mat-select-search
          [formControl]="bankFilterCtrl"
        ></ngx-mat-select-search>
      </mat-option>

      <!-- <mat-option *ngFor="let bank of filteredBanks | async" [value]="bank">
        {{bank.name}}
      </mat-option> -->
      <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize]="42" [style.height.px]="4 * 42">
        <mat-option [value]="{ name: 'any', id: -1 }">Any</mat-option>
        <mat-option
          *cdkVirtualFor="let bank of filteredBanks | async; trackBy: trackBy"
          [value]="bank"
          >{{ bank.name }}</mat-option
        >
      </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</p>
<p>Selected Bank: {{ bankCtrl.value?.name }}</p>
```

ts

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  OnDestroy,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material/select';
import { ReplaySubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { take, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Bank, BANKS } from '../demo-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-single-selection-example',
  templateUrl: './single-selection-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./single-selection-example.component.scss'],
})
export class SingleSelectionExampleComponent
  implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy
{
  /** list of banks */
  protected banks: Bank[] = BANKS;

  /** control for the selected bank */
  public bankCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  /** control for the MatSelect filter keyword */
  public bankFilterCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  /** list of banks filtered by search keyword */
  public filteredBanks: ReplaySubject<Bank[]> = new ReplaySubject<Bank[]>(1);

  @ViewChild('singleSelect', { static: true }) singleSelect: MatSelect;

  /** Subject that emits when the component has been destroyed. */
  protected _onDestroy = new Subject<void>();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // set initial selection

    // load the initial bank list
    this.bankCtrl.setValue(this.banks[10]);
    this.filteredBanks.next(this.getCorrectSlice());

    // listen for search field value changes
    this.bankFilterCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.filterBanks();
      });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {}

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._onDestroy.next();
    this._onDestroy.complete();
  }

  getCorrectSlice(): Bank[] {
    const output = this.banks.slice();
    const bank: Bank = this.bankCtrl.value;
    if (bank) {
      return [bank, ...this.banks];
    }
    return this.banks.slice();
  }

  compareWith(a: Bank, b: Bank) {
    return a && a.name && b && b.name ? a === b : false;
  }

  protected filterBanks() {
    let search = this.bankFilterCtrl.value;
    if (!this.banks || !search) {
      return;
    }
    // get the search keyword
    if (!search) {
      this.filteredBanks.next(this.getCorrectSlice());
      return;
    } else {
      search = search.toLowerCase();
    }
    // filter the banks
    this.filteredBanks.next(
      this.banks.filter((bank) => bank.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1)
    );
  }

  selectionChange(e: any) {
    this.bankFilterCtrl.setValue('');
    this.filteredBanks.next(this.getCorrectSlice());
  }

  trackBy(index: number, item: Bank) {
    return item.id;
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-9fxc91-ighud1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexamples%2F01-single-selection-example%2Fsingle-selection-example.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fexamples%2F01-single-selection-example%2Fsingle-selection-example.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fexamples%2F01-single-selection-example%2Fsingle-selection-example.component.scss)

Comment: After checking with my team, they say that it will be a problem because I have to keep the selected item in its first place because the items are ordered :( I really thought I solved this.

Comment: @helpmecode sorry to hear about that, this is the best I can do for now :(